# How do I wire my ceiling light?

Tags: wiring, ceiling, light

I have 2 black wires, 2 white wires and 2 exposed wires. I connected the light's white to the 2 white wires, the black to the 2 black and the green to the 2 exposed, but when I turn my breaker back on and flip the switch it trips the breaker.

Comment: Do you have any type of electrical tester or meter to identify the hot cable? Does either of the whites have black tape, paint, or ink?

Comment: Is this a new fixture or replacement?

Comment: You should have left it the way you found it.  In the future, don't take apart any more wires than are absolutely necessary.  "How the wires are arranged now" is **the only** documentation on how the circuit is wired.  As you just learned, colors mean nothing.  It gets even worse when you get to 3-way switches.

Answer (score 5):

You have a hot set, and a switch loop.

To test for hot set use the light as a tester, connect to one set, insulate the other set, and turn the breaker on. If the light doesn't come on turn the breaker off and try the other set.

When you have identified the hot set turn the breaker back off, leave the whites connected and disconnect the blacks. Connect the black from the light to the black from the other cable. Mark the white from the other cable with tape, paint, or ink, then connect it to the black that is from the first cable.

Connect all bare and green wires together, then mount fixture.

This is what you should have when done:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the detailed instructions. This was exactly what I needed.